# Why can you use the Maclaurin Series for certain cases of function not about 0?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is it possible  to use the Maclaurin Series in a problem like this one (AP Calculus BC Question 6 from a few years ago)?

> Write the first four nonzero terms and the general term of the Taylor series for $e^{(x-1)^2}$ about $x = 1$.

Shouldn't the Maclaurin Series only work around $x = 0$? Why can you use it about $x = 1$?

Comment: Shift the variable: $u=x-1$. Now it's about $u=0$, yay!

Comment: While substituting it goes back to $x=0$. It's already undergoing a horizontal shift. That means it's really like building a Maclaurin series

Answer (score 1):

Just so there's an answer: The "center" of a (real or complex) power series is one of its least consequential aspects, as far as convergence is concerned. Precisely, if
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k}
  \quad\text{converges for $|x| < R$,}
$$
then
$$
g(x) = f(x - x_{0}) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} (x - x_{0})^{k}
  \quad\text{converges for $|x - x_{0}| < R$.}
$$